# What was the longest time jump in the Back to the Future canon?

Tags: back-to-the-future

The shortest time jump was, presumably, the first; Einstein's trip a single minute forward during the experiment in the Twin Pines Mall parking lot.

What was the longest jump backwards or forwards made by the DeLorean(s) or the Jules Verne during the films, ride, animated series and game?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Main Canon.

In the Back to the Future films, the longest jump seen on screen is from BTTF3; Marty's jump from 1885 to 1985, precisely **100 years into the future** when he uses the stolen time-train to travel home.

The final scenes of BTTF3 (notably the fact that the Jules Verne has been [hover-converted](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Hover_conversion)) would seem to suggest a jump from 1885 to 2015 (**130 years into the future**), but it's not made clear whether this happened in a single jump or multiple jumps.

### TV Canon

In the TV show, Marty and the Doc travel back to the [Jurassic age](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Dinosaur), approximately 180 million years ago. They encounter a [dinosaur](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/bttf/images/7/75/Tiny.png/revision/latest?cb=20101031004350) called Tiny.

### Other Canons

In the [BTTF ride](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future:_The_Ride), the riders experience a jump in to the Cretaceous period where they are attacked by a T-Rex, presumably somewhere around 68 million years into the past.

Comment: Curious how they did the Jurassic/Cretaceous jumps given that the time selector only allows a 4-digit year, and doesn't appear to have support for B.C. dates.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Doc did, after all, build it.  The UI would just be an aid to someone who can take the electronics apart and rewire it.  Or, if you want technobabble, he cross-wired the flux capacitor to boost time traveled by a factor of a million, then set it back 180 years.

Comment: @darrellhoffman - That sounds like an excellent question to ask.

Comment: @Richard - I think someone asked before

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I've been on that ride! If I remember right it was a malfunction, not actually typed in - but it seems like so long ago - I could be misremembering

Comment: @DoubleDouble - If you go to 2:23 in the video above, you can see that they go back in time to the time of the dinosaurs by accidentally ramming the clock-tower **at the moment of the lightning strike**.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a known answer and an unknown possible minimum answer.  The known answer would be from 1955 back to 1885.  The unknown answer could be a minimum of 1885 to 2015, but possibly much more.

It's also not known how long he had to live in the past before he could time travel again. From the age of his kids, it might be that he didn't travel again until 1895 or so. And that would reduce the possible minimum by 10 years. Or did he have the kids in the future, after traveling?

It's difficult to say if Doc went from 1885/1895 in a train directly to 2015, or even further. The train he returns in at the end of Part 3 looks quite a bit more complicated than 2015 technology.  So I'm betting he went from 1895 to 2045 or possibly further.

Comment: This just appears to be my answer, re-worded.

Comment: Fair enough on part of this, but you didn't mention this "It's also not known how long he had to live in the past before he could time travel again." Therefore my answer expanded that premise as well as the premise of a minimum, which you also didn't mention. It is not known whether doc went from 1885,or at what point he started, to what date I  the future, whether 2015 or further.

Comment: Although that's a good point, it's not really an answer in itself.